# How can I send data in backed that has to inserted in a array list using Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list

```
export class AddressProduct extends Component {
state = {
    addProduct: {
        name: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Your Product Name'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        description: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Add Some Product description'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        is_cancellable: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: [{
                        value: 'true',
                        displayValue: 'True'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'false',
                        displayValue: 'False'
                    }
                ]
            },
            validation: {},
            valid: true
        },
        is_retunable: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: [{
                        value: 'true',
                        displayValue: 'True'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'false',
                        displayValue: 'False'
                    }
                ]
            },
            validation: {},
            valid: true
        },
        brand: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Brand Name'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        is_active: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: [{
                        value: 'true',
                        displayValue: 'True'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'false',
                        displayValue: 'False'
                    }
                ]
            },
            validation: {},
            valid: true
        },
        category_name: {
            value: this.props.history.location.state?.categoryName
        }

    },
    formIsValid: false
}

dataPost = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = {};
    for (let addProductData in this.state.addProduct) {
        formData[addProductData] = this.state.addProduct[addProductData].value;
    }
    const newProduct = {
        newProductData: formData
    }
    console.log(newProduct);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
        },
        data: formData,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/seller/productSave/' + this.state.addProduct.category_name.value
    };
    axios(options);
}
checkValidity(value, rules) {
    let isValid = true;

    if (!rules) {
        return true;
    }

    if (rules.required) {
        isValid = value.trim() !== '' && isValid;
    }
    return isValid;
}

inputChangedHandeller = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
    const copyProductFrom = {
        ...this.state.addProduct
    };
    const newCopy = {
        ...copyProductFrom[inputIdentifier]
    };
    newCopy.value = event.target.value;
    newCopy.valid = this.checkValidity(newCopy.value, newCopy.validation);
    newCopy.touched = true;
    copyProductFrom[inputIdentifier] = newCopy;
    let formIsValid = true;
    for (let inputIdentifier in copyProductFrom) {
        formIsValid = copyProductFrom[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid;
    }
    this.setState({
        addProduct: copyProductFrom,
        formIsValid: formIsValid
    });
}


render() {
    const formElementsArray = [];
    for (let key in this.state.addProduct) {
        formElementsArray.push({
            id: key,
            config: this.state.addProduct[key]
        });
    }
    let form = ( <
        form onSubmit = {
            this.dataPost
        } > {
            formElementsArray.map(forElement => ( <
                Input key = {
                    forElement.id
                }
                elementType = {
                    forElement.config.elementType
                }
                elementConfig = {
                    forElement.config.elementConfig
                }
                value = {
                    forElement.config.value
                }
                invalid = {
                    !forElement.config.valid
                }
                shouldValidate = {
                    forElement.config.validation
                }
                touched = {
                    forElement.config.touched
                }
                elementGet = {
                    (event) => this.inputChangedHandeller(event, forElement.id)
                }
                />
            ))
        } <
        button className = "btn btn-primary"
        disabled = {
            !this.state.formIsValid
        } > Submit < /button>&nbsp; <
        /form>
    );
    return ( <
        div >
        <
        div className = {
            classes.Registration
        } > {
            form
        } <
        /div> <
        /div>
    );
}
```

}

**I am trying to push my data to band end api that is in spring it accepts array list.How can I convert this data and send this data as any array list to my back end api.Right now I am getting error Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList`...............................................................................................................................**

Answer (score 0):

you should use `JSON.stringify(yourDataGoesHere)` and then `parse` in the backend. you can use `JSON.parse()` or something specific for Java